# Why aren't I able to send local notifications with Xamarin NotificationManager.notify(..) method

Tags: xamarin, notifications, xamarin.android

I am just trying to send a simple notification.  I start out with this simple interface:

```cs
public interface INotifier
{
    void LocalNotify(string title, string message);

}
```

Then implement the interface in the .droid project like this:

```cs
class PlatformNotifier :INotifier
{

    public void LocalNotify(string title, string message)
    {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(Android.App.Application.Context)
            .SetContentTitle(title)
            .SetContentText(message)
            .SetAutoCancel(true);

        Notification notification = builder.Build();
        notificationManager.Notify(1, notification);
    }
}
```

Before the namespace definition of my implementation I have this line to make it a dependency service

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(PlatformNotifier))]
```

Finally I call the service with the following code

```cs
private void DoneButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    INotifier notifier = DependencyService.Get<INotifier>();
    notifier.LocalNotify( "Test", "this is a notification");           
}
```

Through debugging I have confirmed that the code in the Platform notifier does get reached, and the `Notify(...)` gets called, however no notification shows.

Comment: What Android version are you targeting?

Comment: I am targeting 5.1 I believe

Comment: Okay that rules out needing `NotificationCompat.Builder`. Seems like your approach is right on with [how Xamarin recommends](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/android/local_notifications_in_android/), so I'd suggest trying the current activity instead of the application for context.

Comment: How can I get the current activity? Pass in a context to the LocalNotify method? The DoneButton_Clicked method is in a *.xaml.cs class in the base project

Comment: Take a look at the answer I posted. It has link to CrossCurrentActivity plugin that provides the current activity.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

It might be the context that you are providing to the `Notification.Builder`. Try the current activity instead of the application.

You could use [James Montemagno's CurrentActivity plugin](http://motzcod.es/post/133609925342/access-the-current-android-activity-from-anywhere) to get the current activity.

Install Plugin.CurrentActivity into your Xamarin.Android project via Nuget, then try this:

```cs
...

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity)...

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use that code, will work ;)

In its `Platform Notifier` class in the method `LocalNotify`:

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(Android.App.Application.Context)
    .SetContentTitle(Title)
    .SetContentText(ContentMessage)
    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon);

    // Build the notification:
    Notification notification = builder.Build();

    // Get the notification manager:
    NotificationManager notificationManager = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

    // Publish the notification:
    const int notificationId = 0;
    notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notification);
```